# I need help to understand a lisp program that finds the depth of a list

Tags: list, recursion, lisp, common-lisp, map-function

I need help to understand my code theoretically. Here is my lisp program:

```
(defun depth (lst)

  (if (or (null lst) (atom lst)) 0 

    (+ 1 (apply 'max (mapcar #'depth lst)))

  ))
```

I know it works with this example:

```
(write (depth '((a (b c) d r ((t))))) -> 3
```

I just can't understand the *else* statement of the `IF` statement that I tried.

If you can help me, it will be very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is your code, slightly reformatted:

```
(defun depth (value)
  (if (or (null value) (atom value))
      0
      (+ 1 (apply 'max (mapcar #'depth value)))))
```

I renamed `lst` (you could have written it `list`, by the way) to `value`, because the name is confusing as it suggest that the variable is always a list, which is not true. The function `depth` can be called on any value:

```
(depth "hello")
=> 0

(depth 100)
=> 0
```

The *then* branch of the `if` is evaluated when `value` is NIL or any `atom`. Since `NIL` is also an `atom`, the test expression could be simplified as `(atom value)`. When value is an atom, the depth is zero.

The *else* branch of the `if` is evaluated when `value` is not an atom, which [by definition](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_atom.htm#atom) of `atom` means `value` here is a `cons`. The function also assumes that it is a proper list, and not some circular list.

Since `value` is a list in that branch, we can call `mapcar` on it: `(mapcar #'depth value)`; this is where the function assumes the list is proper.
This computes `(depth v)` for each `v` in `value`. More precisely if `value` is a list of length *n*, then that call to `mapcar` evaluates as a list of numbers `(D1 ... Dn)` where `Di` is `(depth Vi)` for all `i` between 1 and `n`.

So we know that `(apply 'max (mapcar ...))` is `(apply 'max depths)` for some list `depths` of numbers. In general:

```
(apply fn v1 ... vn list)
```

... is a way to call the function object denoted by the `fn` expression with at least `n` elements (`v1` to `vn`), as well as an arbitrary number of additional elements stored in `list`. When you quote the function, as `'max`, or when you write `#'max`, you refer to a function by its name in the function namespace.

Contrast this to the usual way of calling a function:

```
(f x y z)
```

The function name and the number of arguments being passed is fixed: as soon the form is read we knows there is a call to `f` with 3 arguments.

The `apply` function is a built-in that allows you to pass additional arguments in a list, in the last call argument. The above call could be written:

```
(apply #'f x y z ()) ;; note the empty list as a last argument
```

This could also be written:

```
(apply #'f (list x y z)) ;; all arguments in the last list
```

The only difference is probably a matter of runtime efficiency (and with good compilers, maybe there is no difference).

In your example, you do:

```
(apply max depths)
```

Which would be the same as writing (pseudo-code):

```
(max d1 d2 d3 ... dn)
```

... where `depths` is the list `(list d1 d2 ... dn)`.
But we can't literally write them all directly, since the content of the list is only known at runtime.

Thus, the call to apply computes the max depths among all the depths computed recursively. Note that the above is a somewhat improper use of `apply`, since `apply` should not be called with lists of arbitrary size: there is a limit in the standard named [`CALL-ARGUMENTS-LIMIT`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_call_a.htm) that is allowed to be as low as 50 in theory, the maximum size of such a list  (we will see an alternative below).

Finally, `depth` evaluates `(+ 1 ...)` on this result. In other words, the whole expression can be summarized as: **the depth of a list is 1 added to the maximum depth of all its elements.**

#### Using `reduce`

Instead of `apply`, you can use [`REDUCE`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_reduce.htm) to compute `max` successively on a list. This is preferable to `apply` because:

- there is no limitation for the number of elements, like `apply`

  ```
  (reduce 'max depths) ;; works the same, but more reliably
  ```
- there is no need need to build an intermediate list of depths, you iterate over the list of values, call `depth` and directly use the result to compute the max. The skeleton is:

  ```
  (reduce (lambda (max-so-far item) ...)
          value
          :initial-value 0)
  ```

#### Declarative approach

Instead of `reduce`, the `loop` macro can be used as a more readable alternative to express the same computation. I also use `typecase` which in my opinion makes the intent clearer:

```
(defun depth (value)
  (typecase value
    (atom 0)
    (cons (1+ (loop for v in value maximize (depth v))))))
```